# Header differs from implementation in C++

Tags: c++, header-files

Is there a mechanism that checks if the header follows the implementation correctly?

Example

```
//my_pi.cpp
float my_pi(){
    return 3.14;
}


//my_pi.h
int my_pi();


//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "my_pi.h"

int main()
{
    float returned;
    returned = my_pi();
    cout << returned;
}
```

This compiles without error, however it gives the wrong result. I'm just starting to learn C++ and this looks like a very easy way to make bugs which are hard to trace specially when the OOP concepts come into play (classes with large prototypes).

Or is there something I'm missing and its a good thing to be able to define a different header and one just has to be careful?

Comment: have you turned on warning level to max?

Comment: @claptrap I don't believe that will help in this case. There's nothing wrong at the compile stage. And to the linker, everything is fine: `main.cpp` is trying to consume the symbol `_Z5my_piv` and `my_pi.cpp` is producing it. There's no return-type safety.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart So it's possible that for a more complicated class prototype the symbol would be different and there would be a compiler error? Off topic: how do you check the generated symbols?

Comment: `readelf -s` if you're using ELF files (gcc / Linux).

Comment: Name mangling encodes the parameter types into the symbol name, which is necessary because C++ supports overloading. You can [play with it](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/) and see what I mean.

Comment: That's backwards. The **header** defines the interface, and the **source code** should do what the header says it does. The first step is for the source code to `#include` the header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Always* include the header file in the source file that implements it. That doesn't catch all errors but most of them. For instance it would not detect an error in the parameter to a function (because you are allowed multiple functions with the same name which differ only in their parameters), but in this case you'd get a linker error anyway.

Comment: +1 Great advice. But also: since this is C++ wouldn't the names be mangled, ensuring type compatibility? (And causing a link error here)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes I think you're right although a compiler error is better than a linker error.

Comment: Actually in g++ both `int my_pi()` and `float my_pi()` produce the same symbol: `_Z5my_piv` which is [demangled](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/) to `my_pi()`.

Comment: I did wonder, the return type is not part of the function signature, so it doesn't have to be part of name mangling, but I would have thought it would be done that way anyway as a safety feature.

Comment: Yep, I was also surprised that the return type wasn't part of the name.